# Repeater items are not showing horizontally?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to make some image and text as dynamically so i change items in to repeater.data is coming but repeater is showing vertically that is shown horizontally without repeater in html code.so please help to change it into horizontal view  am attaching the images .images shown what i need and how it look like now with my code..

I want to change items align horizontally using repeater now it is showing vertically.so please help me
    [image: actual code]
      [image: my code by using repeater]
    [image: actual design]
[image: my design with repeater]

Comment: any one to help me

Comment: In your question, can you replace the code and markup images by their text version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `col-md-2` divs should naturally appear horizontally within a `row`, but you are giving each item in your repeater their own `container` and `row`. Moving those divs outside of the repeater should fix your problem.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row news-list">
    <asp:Repeater>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          ...
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the display mode to `inline-block` in the `col-md-2` class style and set the size and margin of each block:

```
.col-md-2
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    ...
}
```